# AngularJS - create dynamic filter which changes with each ng-repeat iteration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of regions, and each region has a drop-down list that should show only the cities in that particular region. I used a nested `ng-repeat` for this:

```
<li ng-click="filter_region($event)" ng-repeat="region in regions">
       <span>{{region.region}}</span>
    <ul class="cityFilter" >
            <li ng-repeat="city in cities | filter:cityList">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{city.id}}" ng-model="city.checked" ng-checked="city.checked">
                <span>{{city.city}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </li>
```

I need cityList as a dynamic filter. Each city should be filtered based on the current region.
i.e. the region value needs to change with each iteration of the outer loop

pseudo-code for the filter:

```
$scope.cityList = function (item) {
            if (item.region_id == myDynamicRegion) 
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Is it doable?

Comment: please put code on jsfiddle/plunker

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is doable. You can pass arguments to your filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items |filter:x"></div>
```

And the filter:

```
 yourApp.filter('filter', function () {
        return function (item, x) {
            // Do the magic.
        };
 });
```

Comment: Where do I manipulate the value to match the current region? I need the value to change for each iteration

Comment: Can't you pass the region to the filter and show/hide the city based on that region?